# Project1.exe has stopped working for no reason (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a C++ code in dev C++ where all of the sudden it just says project 1.exe has stopped working and i dont know why

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *upasscode;
    char *spasscode;
    spasscode = ("FISH");
    cout<<"ENTER PASWWORD\n";
    cout<<"--------------\n";
    cin>> upasscode;
    if ( upasscode != spasscode ) {
         goto incorrect;
    }
    else {
         goto correct;
    }
    incorrect:
    cout<<"INCORRECT";
    system("pause>null");
    system("EXIT");
    correct:
    cout<<"Welcome!";
    system("pause>null");
    system("EXIT");
}
```

Comment: Well, there is a reason, and I suspect it has to do with accessing memory that isn't yours.

Comment: Who taught you `goto`?

Comment: I think the best part is the goto statements are inside of if statements where the code that the goto statements execute could be put anyway :) Just a tip bud, avoid goto statements. They are very bad and are looked upon very poorly.

Comment: You don't want to compare character pointers - use strcmp.   Also, cin probably won't know how to allocate memory for u pass code.

Comment: Forget `strcmp`. Use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that your `incorrect` code flows into your `correct` code, there is nothing to change the path of execution.
If you like `goto`, I suggest the following:

```
incorrect:
cout<<"INCORRECT";
system("pause>null");
system("EXIT");
goto end_of_program;
correct:
cout<<"Welcome!";
system("pause>null");
system("EXIT");
end_of_program:
return 0;
```

Or you could simplify:

```
incorrect:
cout<<"INCORRECT";
goto end_of_program;
correct:
cout<<"Welcome!";
end_of_program:
system("pause>null");
return 0;
```

Alas, probably something better:

```
int main()
{
    char *upasscode;
    char *spasscode;
    spasscode = ("FISH");
    cout<<"ENTER PASWWORD\n";
    cout<<"--------------\n";
    cin>> upasscode;
    if ( upasscode != spasscode )
    {
         cout << "INCORRECT\n";
    }
    else
    {
         cout << "Welcome!\n";
    }
    system("pause>null");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Do you really need the `system("EXIT")` function call or will a return (exit) from `main` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cin >> upasscode;
> ```

`upasscode` is a `char*` that does not have memory allocated to it. When you extract input into `upasscode` you will be dereferencing addresses that you do not own, thus Undefined Behavior.

Instead you can use `std::string` which will dynamically-resize itself to accommodate extra characters.

> ```
> std::string spasscode;
> std::cin >> spasscode;
> ```

Moreover, you're using `goto` which is a very bad programming practice. You can always restructure your program in a better way than that.

Comment: thanks for all the advice  i learned goto from batch and it just  turned out to work i dont use them anymore and i do use std::string now so thanks

Comment: @codingadam Good to hear from you. And I'm glad I could help. :)